# PhoneGap Facebook Plugin for Android: FB.login results in "Something Went Wrong" error

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm running Android 2.3 on a device and PhoneGap 2.6. I've followed the instructions on the FB SDK documentation and on the README for this plugin. When I run my app on my device, I get the message "Cordova Facebook Connect plugin initialized successfully.", but when I call FB.login, I get the following ever-so-helpful alert message:

Something Went Wrong
android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager

Any ideas what this could be? I've spent a day and a half now trying to fix it. I've re-installed the SDK and plugin, I've regenerated hash keys, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the FacebookSDK project - go on the java build path and check android-support-v4.jar (somehow this was unchecked on mine after an android sdk update... )

then just go on Project > clean and rerun the application :)